# Can I build SSIS package in a visual studio to .exe file

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I created a SSIS package in visual studio for getting data from web service and insert data to a SQL Server.

If I don't want to deploy SSIS package to a SQL Server
Is it possible to built a SSIS package to .exe file?

I would like to run the .exe file with double click and then the package will process to get data from web service to --> SQL Server.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no, you can't make an SSIS package into an exe file, but you can imitate the concept. What you will want to do is create a windows batch file to allow you to automatically run the packages via Command Prompt and you will need to use Dtexec. Here is what your batch file will look like:

```
@ECHO OFF
Some comment about what the package is doing

Dtexec /f "C:\some\file\path\YourPackage.dtsx
```

Then once you save the notepad as a windows batch file you will be able to double click/open the batch file and it will run your package in the Command Prompt.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to build a self-executing SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

We also have the issues since our devops is in charge of deployment and doesn't want to install SSDT.

1. build it to get .ispac
2. Change the connection information and credential, then execute each package

```
dtexec /Project "C:\temp\test.ispac" /Package "test.dtsx" ^
/conn "TEST";"\"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=testdb;Uid=tester;Pwd=tester;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;\"" ^
/conn "DEST";"\"Data Source=DEST_Server;Initial Catalog=DEST_DB;Uid=tester;Pwd=tester;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;\""
```

3. You need 'DTexec' from you SSMS for basic functionalities, but it is necessary to have Integration Services installed to ensure all of functionalities properly work.